# GeoServer Layer with point and polygon simultaneously

Tags: polygon, layer, point, geoserver

Is it possible to have a Layer on GeoServer with polygon and point representations at the same time?

I have a data model that can be represented through a point, a polygon, or both. Do I have to have two Layers in GeoServer, one for the points and one for the polygons, or is there a way to have both representations in the same Layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just treat the geometry as a generic geometry, GeoServer is fine with that.

The question is then how you **display** the data if you want to serve it as a WMS layer(s). This is covered in the [styling mixed geometry section](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/tipstricks/mixed-geometries.html) of the manual.

Comment: I have separate geometry columns, just like one of the options for restructuring the data that is in the manual. But the layer always assumes the Point representation, and I can never see the Polygon. From the documentation I can't tell if there is any additional configuration I should do. Any suggestions?